# Can't find Serial Number attribute for PL2303 device in linux

Tags: c#, linux, serial-port, usb, tty

When i run the following command after connecting PL2303 USB to serial converter to my ubuntu system:

`dmesg | grep ttyUSB`

i get:

`usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

then i run:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0
```

i get:

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2':
KERNELS=="1-2"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
DRIVERS=="usb"
ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
ATTRS{configuration}==""
ATTRS{devnum}=="27"
ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b"
ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Prolific Technology Inc. "
ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
ATTRS{product}=="USB-Serial Controller D"
ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
ATTRS{speed}=="12"
ATTRS{urbnum}=="20"
ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
```

But no

> ATTRS{serial}
>   is found for the above PL2303 USB to serial converter.
>   Can anyone please tell me why? I get the serial attribute for all other USB devices

Comment: why does it have  c# tag?

Comment: Is it possible that the attribute was simply not written into the device by the manufacturer?

Comment: Each manufacturer has there own driver for USB to serial port.  Make sure you are using the recommended vendors driver. The default driver is the Microsoft Driver which does not work with all vendors hardware.

Comment: okay so it can be a driver issue. But without driver how is my linux system detecting all the details of the USB device?

Answer (score 3):

[The datasheet for the PL2303 serial converter chip](http://www.stkaiser.de/anleitung/files/PL2303.pdf) includes a description of the EEPROM configuration data for the chip on page 11.

The EEPROM can specify the USB product and vendor IDs for the chip, so instead of using the generic USB-to-serial converter ID, someone using this chip in their products can use an ID that is specific to their product, allowing for seamless auto-detection and use of the product-specific driver, if desired. One would expect that the serial number might also be stored in that EEPROM. But there is no place for a serial number in the EEPROM data layout.

In fact, **the entire datasheet does not document any way to retrieve an unique serial number from this serial converter at all.** So I must conclude that this serial converter chip series simply does not have unique serial numbers, at least not in its earlier chip revisions (the datasheet is from year 2005).